# Output a nested list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This shouldn't be that difficult, but my brain is getting tired of trying to figure it out.  I can't seem to figure out how to loop through my lists and output a ul list.  I have two different array objects, one containing the parent nodes and the second containing the child nodes.  The parent nodes have a key of submenu:true|false depending on if they have children.  This is what I've done so far:

*widgetArray*

```
{
  label:string,
  documentUrl:string, 
  submenu:boolean
}
```

```
widgetArray.map((widget:any, index:number) => {
  if (widget.submenu) {
    return subDocumentMenu.map((document:any) => {
      if (widget.label === document.parent) {
        return (
            <li key={index}>{widget.label}
              <ul>
                <li key={index}><button onClick={() => toggleDocumentOverlay(document.dataUrl, document.label)} className={`${widget.label === widgetName ? 'active' : ''}`}>{document.label}</button></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          )
      }
    });
  } else {
    return <li key={index}><button onClick={() => toggleDocumentOverlay(widget.dataUrl, widget.label)} className={`${widget.label === widgetName ? 'active' : ''}`}>{widget.label}</button></li>
  }
});
```

I realize the parent node will be output twice, but I'm a little confused on how to break this out so that the parent node only outputs once, while the children loop.

The expected final result would be to have something like:

```
<ul>
  <li>label</li>
  <li>label
    <ul>
      <li>label</li>
      <li>label</li>
      <li>label</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>label</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have now added an example of the widgetArray.

Comment: Can you provide what your `widgetArray` array structure looks like, and a more complete picture of the render function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning tour `<li> </li>`  in the wrong place .Try this way

```
if (widget.submenu) {
      return (
        <li key={index}>

          {widget.label}

          {subDocumentMenu.map((document) => {
            if (widget.label === document.parent) {
              return <li key={index}><button onClick={() => toggleDocumentOverlay(document.dataUrl, document.label)} className={`${widget.label === widgetName ? 'active' : ''}`}>{document.label}</button></li>
            }
           })
          }
        
        </li>
   );
}
```